# Openshift - Using a service account to login to the docker registry

Tags: openshift, docker-registry

I am currently trying to use the projects defaults service account "builder" to login to my projects Openshift docker registry to push an image to it afterwards.

The login using the oc cli is successful but when I am trying to login to the docker registry:

`docker login -u $(oc whoami) -p $(oc whoami --show-token) registry.pro-eu-west-1.openshift.com:443`

I am facing:

`Error response from daemon: Get https://registry.pro-eu-west-1.openshift.com:443/v2/: unauthorized: authentication required`

It seems like that the builder service account is not having the permission to login to the Openshifts docker registry, although it is having the role `system:image-builder` which is having the description:

```
Grants the rights to build, push and pull images from within a project.
...
```

Any thoughts what might go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I don't know why `docker login` doesn't work the way you expect, you can cause your local docker to be logged-in to the cluster registry as the current `oc` user, using the following:

```
oc registry login
```

If you want to login as a ServiceAccount such as `builder` (if that's not the user that you're logged-in with using `oc`, you can use the `-z` option (assuming you're in the project in which the ServiceAccount is):

```
oc registry login -z builder
```

Also remember that within the cluster, the `builder` ServiceAccount has access to the image registry using a Secret called something like `builder-dockercfg-zftv4`.

---

If you do still want/need to use something other than `oc` to login (such as with some tool that doesn't deal with `~/.docker/config.json`), then to login as a service account you'll need to change the username to be the fully-qualified ServiceAccount name, but replace colons with hyphens.

E.g. if you've got a project called `my-project` that has a `builder` ServiceAccount, then the fully-qualified name in Kubernetes would be:

```
system:serviceaccount:my-project:builder
```

but as a registry username for the in-cluster registry in OpenShift, it would be:

```
system-serviceaccount-my-project-builder
```